# Quantum Computing: Preparation of the Bell state Notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, notation, quantum-computer, linear-algebra

I was watching some lectures on qubits. They were talking about how to generate a Bell state. They described it as follows:

> 1. Prepare state 00:
>    $$\left |0 \right> \otimes \left |0 \right>$$
> 2. Apply the Hadamard:
>    $$ (H \otimes I)(\left |0 \right> \otimes \left |0 \right> ) = \left |+0 \right> = \frac{\left|00 \right> + \left |10 \right>}{\sqrt{2}}$$
> 3. Apply CNOT to go from state 00 + 10 to state 00 + 11,
>    $$ CNOT = \left |0 \right> \left <0 \right| \otimes I + \left |1 \right> \left<1 \right| \otimes X $$
>    such that:
>    $$CNOT\times\frac{\left|00 \right> + \left |10 \right>}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\left |0 \right> \left <0|0 \right> \otimes I \left |0 \right> + \left |0 \right> \left <0|1 \right> \otimes I\left |1 \right> + \left |1 \right> \left <1|0 \right> \otimes X \left |0 \right> + \left |1 \right> \left <1|1 \right> \otimes X \left |0 \right>  }{\sqrt{2}} = \left | \Omega \right >$$

I am not sure I can follow how the product of the CNOT and the state 00 + 10, can be expanded out as written above. Hope you guys can help me out.
This is not part of an assignment nor a check my work problem. Although, it is obvious that this is not a homework question; it must be stated as some may interpret it as HW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in your second term. If $I$ is the identity, then I believe it should be $\lvert 0\rangle\langle 0\lvert 1\rangle\otimes I\lvert 0\rangle$ instead of $\lvert 0\rangle\langle 0\lvert 1\rangle\otimes I\lvert 1\rangle$.

Anyway, let's do it step by step.
We have $$CNOT\times\frac{\lvert 00\rangle+\lvert 10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}=\bigg(\lvert 0\rangle\langle 0 \lvert\otimes I+\lvert 1\rangle\langle 1 \lvert\otimes X\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\lvert 00\rangle+\lvert 10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)\\=\bigg(\lvert 0\rangle\langle 0 \lvert\otimes I+\lvert 1\rangle\langle 1 \lvert\otimes X\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\lvert 0\rangle\otimes\lvert 0\rangle+\lvert 1\rangle\otimes\lvert 0\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)\\=\frac{\lvert 0\rangle\langle 0\lvert 0\rangle\otimes I\lvert 0\rangle+\lvert 0\rangle\langle 0\lvert 1\rangle\otimes I\lvert 0\rangle+\lvert 1\rangle\langle 1\lvert 0\rangle\otimes X\lvert 0\rangle+\lvert 1\rangle\langle 1\lvert 1\rangle\otimes X\lvert 0\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$